# compile qt code using gcc in ubuntu

Tags: matlab, qt, ubuntu, gcc

I am new with Linux. I want to compile my code which written in qt creator using gcc in terminal. I don't know how should I do this task. the output will be called in Matlab. please give me information in this area. I search through the internet but i didn't find useful information to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Compile from QtCreator, check the "Compiler" output tab, it will report you most of the gcc commands invoked. You then just need to run them from the terminal...it should work, QtCreator does nothing more.

Comment: Tnx, but I don't understand, what do you mean with Compiler output tab?

Comment: In QtCreator, on the bottom-right area: http://tulip.labri.fr/Documentation/4_4/tulip-dev/html/_images/install_linux_qt_build_release_compil_done.png

Comment: Aha Thanks. Is it possible to run the output without using sudo in the terminal?

Comment: sudo should never be necessary for compiling anything.

Answer (score 0):

In QT Creator select "New project" -> Non-QT project -> plain C or C++ application, you can then edit your source in QT Creator, go to a Terminal & compile it using gcc or make your own makefile. From the Matlab instructions "The exclamation point character (!) sometimes called bang, is a shell escape. The character indicates that the rest of the input line is a command to the operating system. Use it to invoke utilities or call other executable programs without quitting MATLAB®".